# Limit the Choices shown from ManyToMany ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I limit the values returned via the ManyToMany relationship and thus displayed in the `<SELECT>` field on my form to only show the spots which were created by the currently logged in user?

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
    ...
    spots = models.ManyToManyField(to='Spot', blank=True, )

    class Spot(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, editable=False)
        spot_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Project, Spot


class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ('owner', )


class SpotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Spot
        exclude = ('owner', )
```

I'm using GenericViews for Update and Create and currently see all of the entries everyone has made into Spots when I'm updating or creating a Project. I want to see only the entries entered by the logged in user. For completeness sake, yes, the `project.owner` and `spot.owner` were set to User when they were created.

I've tried def **INIT** in the forms.py and using limit_choices_to on the manytomany field in the model. Either I did those both wrong or that's not the right way to do it.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above, Dean's answer was really close, but didn't work for me. Primarily because request is not accessible in the view directly. Maybe it is in older Django versions? I'm on 1.9. Thank you Dean, you got me over the hump!

The gist of what's going on is adding User into the kwargs in the View, passing that to the ModelForm, remove User from the kwargs and use it to filter the Spots before the form is shown.

This is the code that worked for my project:

views.py

```
class ProjectUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Project
    success_url = reverse_lazy('projects-mine')
    form_class = ProjectForm

def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(ProjectUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(ProjectUpdate, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
    return kwargs
```

forms.py

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ('owner', 'whispir_id')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['spots'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Spot.objects.filter(owner=user_id))


class SpotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Spot
        exclude = ('owner', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(SpotForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['spot_name'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Spot.objects.filter(owner=user_id))
```

Comment: I'm using 1.8, by the way you are using class-based views that's why my method in views.py did not work the same as yours. But glad to see that you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in your forms.py

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        exclude = ('owner', )

    def __init__(self, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['spots'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, queryset=Project.objects.filter(owner=user_id))


class SpotForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Spot
        exclude = ('owner', )

    def __init__(self, user_id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields['spot_name'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, queryset=Spot.objects.filter(owner=user_id))
```

in your views.py

```
user_id = Project.objects.get(owner=request.user).owner
project_form = ProjectForm(user_id)
spot_form = SpotForm(user_id)
```

Comment: I think we're on different versions because your answer didn't work for me, but it was _really_ close and the logic was what I needed to see.  The main issue is you can't access the request object like that in a genric view. You have to override a method or something and then you can access it via self.request. I'll post the answer in a second.